# How to get output objects on screen?

Tags: java, object, constructor

I am working on an assignment where I must instance several different objects and format them on the screen. I am having trouble getting the strings to output properly; in place of text I get an output like this

```
run:
First Name  Last Name   Student ID Number   
studentdemo.StudentDemo@6d06d69c
studentdemo.StudentDemo@7852e922
studentdemo.StudentDemo@4e25154f
studentdemo.StudentDemo@70dea4e
studentdemo.StudentDemo@5c647e05
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here is my main

```
package studentdemo;
public class MainStudent {public static void main(String[] args) {
StudentDemo student1 = new StudentDemo("Peter\t","Adams\t","123546\t");
StudentDemo student2 = new StudentDemo("James\t","Clark\t","654332\t");
StudentDemo student3 = new 
StudentDemo("Christopher\t","Colombo\t","223344\t");
StudentDemo student4 = new StudentDemo("Amy\t","Tan\t","997766\t");
StudentDemo student5 = new 
StudentDemo("Marry\t","Madison\t","6543321\t");
System.out.println("First Name\t"+"Last Name\t"+"Student ID Number\t");
System.out.println(student1);
System.out.println(student2);
System.out.println(student3);
System.out.println(student4);
System.out.println(student5);

}

}
```

and here is my other class

```
package studentdemo;
public class StudentDemo {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String studentIdNumber;

public StudentDemo(String firstName, String lastName, String 
studentIdNumber) {
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.studentIdNumber = studentIdNumber;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setStudentIdNubmer(String studentIdNumber) {
    this.studentIdNumber = studentIdNumber;
}
public String getStudentIdNumber() {
    return studentIdNumber;
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to print the object (student1) instead of the properties of object.

Please try:

> System.out.println(student1.getFirstName()+"\t"+student1.getLastName()+"\t"+student1.getStudentIdNumber());

instead of:

> `System.out.println(student1);`

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to output like so:

```
System.out.println(student1.getFirstName() + " " + student1.getLastName());
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to override the toString() method in your `StudentDemo` class. For example:

```
public class StudentDemo {
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " " + this.studentIdNumber;
    }
}
```

Now when you create a new student object, ie `StudentDemo student1 = new StudentDemo();`, if you do `System.out.prntln(student1);`, the toString() method will automatically be called.